# Jquery lightbox image gallery on a seperate thumbnail click

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, typo3

I am trying to invoke a jquery lightbox gallery on a thumbnail click. But it does not work.

Here is the html code -

```
<a class="launchlightbox" href="#"><img src="image_thumb.jpg" alt="" class="small_image"></a>

<div id="gallery">
    <a class="lightboxgallery" href="image1.jpg" id="counter-1"><img src="image1.jpg"></a>
    <a class="lightboxgallery" href="image2.jpg" id="counter-2"><img src="image2.jpg"></a>
    <a class="lightboxgallery" href="image3.jpg" id="counter-3"><img src="image3.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

I've wriiten a Jquery code to invoke the gallery-

```
$('.launchlightbox').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();    
     $(this).next('.lightboxgallery').lightBox();
});
```

But it does not help me. The JS and CSS files for Jquery lightbox plugin also included.

Is there any solution to invoke the lightbox gallery on a seperate thumbnail click?
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are only including jQuery/jQuery Lightbox:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.lightbox-0.4.js"></script>
```

Make sure you have the CSS (and make sure media="screen" is there):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.lightbox-0.4.css" media="screen" />
```

Also, the code you are using for starting the lightbox is not needed - no need to reference the link you clicked on to start lightbox on something else.

```
$('a.launchlightbox').click(function(){
    $("a.lightboxgallery").first().lightBox();
    return false;
});
```

Also, since lightbox loads its image from the URL located in the href attribute of the a tag that `lightBox()` is called on (and not from the image tag inside the link), you can remove all of the image tags within `#gallery a` which will save you from initially loading  a bunch of giant images.

Comment: This is an another method to get it-

$('.launchlightbox').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#counter-1').trigger('click');
 });

Comment: Yes, but that is far more convoluted and calling methods that do not need to be invoked. If you plan on using ID's you can replace my $("a.lightboxgallery").first().lightBox(); simply with $("#counter-1').lightBox(); There is absolutely no reason to use trigger or preventDefault.

Comment: Thanks Jack for your valuable feedback.

Comment: If you like the feedback, please mark my response as an answer - this way it shows your question was answered (and also shows you accept questions to give people in the future a reason to answer your questions!) If my answer does NOT answer your question, please clarify further so I can modify my answer to completely address any remaining concerns.

Comment: May be its is a solution.But in my case your code does not help me.